# Incrementing AverageTimer32 performance counters

Tags: c#, performancecounter, postsharp

I'm moving some instrumentation into PostSharp aspects, basically the code which is incrementing the timing counters looks something like the following:

```
MyPerformanceCounter.IncrementBy(elapsed);
MyPerformanceCounterBase.Increment();
```

This works fine and I see the correct values getting updated in Perfmon (MyPerformanceCounter is an AverageTimer32, MyPerformanceCounterBase is an AverageBase).

However whilst doing this I noticed that there were already a couple of instrumentation aspects floating around:

[This one by Marcin Kaluza](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/marcinkaluza/archive/2009/10/11/aop-performance-counters-and-the-big-red-button.aspx)

[and this very similar one from the PostSharp examples](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/monitoring#performance-counters)

In both of them they only have the first line - the increment on the AverageBase base is missing. If I try this then the counter stops working (no errors, but nothing visible in perfmon).

Am I missing something? It seems to be too much of a coincidence for both of these implementations to not need the explicit update to the base counter. I'm using Vista 64 on machine where I'm testing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the PostSharp web site, I (shamefully) think I did not really test them, and now, looking at the documentation, I see you're probably right.

Comment: Ah, OK that clears that up then - thanks for looking into it!